# Let $G$ be a group and $x$ be a fixed element of $G$. Prove that $G$ is a group under the operation $*$ where $a*b=axb$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $x$ be a fixed element of $G$. Show that $G$ is a group under the operation $*$ where $a*b=axb$.

I need to prove this by showing the $3$ properties of a group, someone please show how to do the first and then I'll try to do the others.

Comment: It's bad form to put the main question *only* in the title. You ought to copy it to the body of the post too.

Comment: Rolled back an edit which changed the $x$ to a $\times$. It seemed... mistaken.

Comment: What is my question missing ?

Comment: context... and a statement of the question in the body, to name a few things.

Comment: @rschwieb I edited as you suggested.

Comment: Good... if you added work for the parts you were able to accomplish, I would even join in reopening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right. The first one is (usually) associativity. Take $a,b,c\in G$. Then\begin{align}(a*b)*c&=(axb)xc\\&=ax(bxc)\\&=a*(b*c).\end{align}

Comment: Could you please show the other proofs ? I tried to do the others but they are wrong according to my teacher.

Comment: @hjx The identity element is $x^{-1}$, because $a*x^{-1}=axx^{-1}=a$ and $x^{-1}*a=x^{-1}xa=e$. FInally, the inverse of $a$ is $x^{-1}a^{-1}$. Can you prove this one?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But I'm confused about $x^{-1}*a=x^{-1}xa=e$, why is this equal to e ?

Comment: My mistake. What I meant was $x^{-1}*a=x^{-1}xa=a$.

Comment: How Can I prove that the inverse of a exists ?

Comment: @hjx I don't know if you can, but I can. The inverse of $a$ is $x^{-1}a^{-1}x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 6):

For any bijection $\varphi: G\to G$, the binary operator 
$$a*b:=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(a)\varphi(b))$$
always makes $G$ a group with identity $\varphi^{-1}(1)$.

In this place, $\varphi: g\mapsto xg$.

Comment: This even works for any bijection $\varphi: X\to G$, where $X$ is a set and turns $X$ into a group isomorphic to $G$. This technique is called *transport of structure*.